# Android app root permission?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, root, superuser

I want to use "su" in my app
but here is some problem

Code:

```
String command[]={"su","-c","ls /data/data/package.name/databases"};
```

My phone not root, but My APP need root permission.
Problem is : Is my phone need root?

Is this possible? Not root phone and APP get root permission?

By the way, my English is not very good, please forgive me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer:

**It is not possible.**

Why:

The user executing your application has not root-rights. Any way to gain root access would violate the user concept and besides that be a huge security issue.

Comment: Futher more,  su command appears only after rooting the device.  Beacause of this is a programm i can not lauch it if no root and no sych programm exists.